# Hibernate Search error after deleting entity

Tags: hibernate, jpa, lucene, hibernate-search

I´m using Hibernate Search 5.3 together with JPA. If I delete a file from my MySQL database, I get the following stacktrace:

```
Information:   Delete User ENTERED !!!
Warnung:   DTX5014: Caught exception in beforeCompletion() callback:
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion)
at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext$DelegateToSynchronizationOnBeforeTx.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:177)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:715)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:389)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:516)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:119)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:50)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:452)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:854)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:719)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy514.deleteUser(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:396)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:108)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:63)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:101)
at de.zerrenda.zerrendaee6.beans.UserService$-722795749$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.deleteUser(Unknown Source)
at de.zerrenda.zerrendaee6.data.UserListProducer.onUserDeleted(UserListProducer.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:274)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:261)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:240)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:170)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:166)
at org.jboss.weld.event.TransactionalObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(TransactionalObserverNotifier.java:44)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:120)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:113)
at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:79)
at de.zerrenda.zerrendaee6.controller.UserEditController.deleteUser(UserEditController.java:390)
at de.zerrenda.zerrendaee6.controller.UserEditController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deleteUser(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:326)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:536)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:269)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at de.zerrenda.zerrendaee6.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:40)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.initializeCollectionFromCache(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:129)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1897)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:558)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:260)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:294)
at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.appendContainedInWorkForInstance(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:225)
at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.WorkPlan$PerEntityWork.processContainedIn(WorkPlan.java:535)
at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.WorkPlan$PerClassWork.processContainedInAndPrepareExecution(WorkPlan.java:296)
at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.WorkPlan.processContainedInAndPrepareExecution(WorkPlan.java:131)
at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.WorkQueue.prepareWorkPlan(WorkQueue.java:113)
at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.BatchedQueueingProcessor.prepareWorks(BatchedQueueingProcessor.java:55)
at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.beforeCompletion(PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.java:74)
at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext$DelegateToSynchronizationOnBeforeTx.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:174)
... 96 more

Warnung: EJB5184:A system exception occurred during an invocation on EJB UserServiceBean, method: public void de.zerrenda.zerrendaee6.beans.UserServiceBean.deleteUser(de.zerrenda.zerrendaee6.entities.User)
Warnung:   javax.ejb.EJBException: Transaction aborted
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:725)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.postInvokeTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:503)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvokeTx(BaseContainer.java:4475)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:2009)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.BaseContainer.postInvoke(BaseContainer.java:1979)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandler.java:220)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.invoke(EJBLocalObjectInvocationHandlerDelegate.java:88)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy514.deleteUser(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.weld.util.reflection.Reflections.invokeAndUnwrap(Reflections.java:396)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.invoke(EnterpriseBeanProxyMethodHandler.java:108)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(EnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:56)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.invoke(InjectionPointPropagatingEnterpriseTargetBeanInstance.java:63)
at org.jboss.weld.bean.proxy.ProxyMethodHandler.invoke(ProxyMethodHandler.java:101)
at de.zerrenda.zerrendaee6.beans.UserService$-722795749$Proxy$_$$_Weld$EnterpriseProxy$.deleteUser(Unknown Source)
at de.zerrenda.zerrendaee6.data.UserListProducer.onUserDeleted(UserListProducer.java:90)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at org.jboss.weld.injection.MethodInjectionPoint.invokeOnInstanceWithSpecialValue(MethodInjectionPoint.java:93)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:274)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.sendEvent(ObserverMethodImpl.java:261)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverMethodImpl.notify(ObserverMethodImpl.java:240)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:170)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(ObserverNotifier.java:166)
at org.jboss.weld.event.TransactionalObserverNotifier.notifyObserver(TransactionalObserverNotifier.java:44)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.notifyObservers(ObserverNotifier.java:120)
at org.jboss.weld.event.ObserverNotifier.fireEvent(ObserverNotifier.java:113)
at org.jboss.weld.event.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:79)
at de.zerrenda.zerrendaee6.controller.UserEditController.deleteUser(UserEditController.java:390)
at de.zerrenda.zerrendaee6.controller.UserEditController$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.deleteUser(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
at javax.el.ELUtil.invokeMethod(ELUtil.java:326)
at javax.el.BeanELResolver.invoke(BeanELResolver.java:536)
at javax.el.CompositeELResolver.invoke(CompositeELResolver.java:256)
at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:269)
at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:304)
at org.jboss.weld.util.el.ForwardingMethodExpression.invoke(ForwardingMethodExpression.java:40)
at org.jboss.weld.el.WeldMethodExpression.invoke(WeldMethodExpression.java:50)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:87)
at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.broadcast(UIData.java:1108)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:790)
at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1282)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:198)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:646)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:344)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at de.zerrenda.zerrendaee6.filter.LoginFilter.doFilter(LoginFilter.java:40)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:256)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:316)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:357)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:260)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:188)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:191)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:168)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:189)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:288)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:136)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:114)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:838)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:113)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:115)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:55)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:135)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:564)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:544)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.transaction.RollbackException: Transaction marked for rollback.
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:490)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.commit(JavaEETransactionManagerSimplified.java:854)
at com.sun.ejb.containers.EJBContainerTransactionManager.completeNewTx(EJBContainerTransactionManager.java:719)
... 88 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Error while indexing in Hibernate Search (before transaction completion)
at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext$DelegateToSynchronizationOnBeforeTx.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:177)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$BeforeTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:715)
at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.beforeTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:389)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:516)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.beforeCompletion(SynchronizationCallbackCoordinatorNonTrackingImpl.java:119)
at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.synchronization.internal.RegisteredSynchronization.beforeCompletion(RegisteredSynchronization.java:50)
at com.sun.enterprise.transaction.JavaEETransactionImpl.commit(JavaEETransactionImpl.java:452)
... 90 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.initializeCollectionFromCache(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:129)
at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.onInitializeCollection(DefaultInitializeCollectionEventListener.java:76)
at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.initializeCollection(SessionImpl.java:1897)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection$4.doWork(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:558)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.withTemporarySessionIfNeeded(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:260)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:554)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.read(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:142)
at org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.iterator(PersistentBag.java:294)
at org.hibernate.search.engine.spi.AbstractDocumentBuilder.appendContainedInWorkForInstance(AbstractDocumentBuilder.java:225)
at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.WorkPlan$PerEntityWork.processContainedIn(WorkPlan.java:535)
at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.WorkPlan$PerClassWork.processContainedInAndPrepareExecution(WorkPlan.java:296)
at org.hibernate.search.engine.impl.WorkPlan.processContainedInAndPrepareExecution(WorkPlan.java:131)
at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.WorkQueue.prepareWorkPlan(WorkQueue.java:113)
at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.BatchedQueueingProcessor.prepareWorks(BatchedQueueingProcessor.java:55)
at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.beforeCompletion(PostTransactionWorkQueueSynchronization.java:74)
at org.hibernate.search.backend.impl.EventSourceTransactionContext$DelegateToSynchronizationOnBeforeTx.doBeforeTransactionCompletion(EventSourceTransactionContext.java:174)
... 96 more
```

To me it looks like Hibernate Search is trying to rebuild the index, before the transaction of the database has finished.

My question is now, how can I tell Hibernate Search to rebuild the index, AFTER the transaction has finished?

I have found some simular questions, but they used Spring configuration, which doesn´t help me much in my situation.

Here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
<!-- Hibernate Configuration -->
<persistence-unit name="ZerrendaPU" transaction-type="JTA">
<provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
<jta-data-source>jdbc/zerrendadb</jta-data-source>
<properties>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
  <property name="hibernate.transaction.jta.platform" value="org.hibernate.service.jta.platform.internal.SunOneJtaPlatform"/>
  <!-- Hibernate Search Configuration -->
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.directory_provider" value="filesystem"/>
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.indexBase" value="/opt/glassfish4/var/lucene/indexes"/>
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.worker.scope" value="transaction"/>
  <!-- DEFAULT -->
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.worker.execution" value="sync"/>
  <!-- DEFAULT -->
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.worker.backend" value="lucene"/>
  <!-- DEFAULT -->
  <property name="hibernate.search.default.reader.strategy" value="shared"/>
  <!-- DEFAULT -->
  <property name="hibernate.search.erroer_handler" value="log"/>
  <!-- DEFAULT -->
  <property name="hibernate.search.lucene_version" value="4.10.4"/>
  <property name="hibernate.search.analyzer" value="customAnalyzer"/>
</properties>
```

I also tried to change the PersistenceContext Type to EXTENDED, like I´ve seen in another topic, but this did not solve the problem.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem.

I had a mistake in my sql database. I missed out to set the cascade type for every associated entity.

After I set the type to CascadeType.XXX everything works fine